# How to define a KeySelector in Flink of Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I have a streaming process basically looks like this

```
Stream(Int, Boolean, Int).Keyby(0, 1).Window().process()
```

The key point is that I want to define a combined key and then process it. However if I use `keyby(0, 1)` and `process(... Key: (Int, Boolean), ...)`, the key type in process always prompt error. I tried to define `keyby(_._1, _._2)`, but not correct.

So, anyway to define a combined key using scala so that I can infer the key type such like `(Int, Boolean)` in the following process function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `input.keyBy(0, 1).timeWindow(Time.days(1))` creates a `KeyedStream[(Int, Boolean, Int), Tuple]` where `Tuple` is Flink's tuple class. This will also be the type of the key parameter of the `process` function. In order to access the fields of a `Tuple` you need to call `tuple.[T]getField(idx)` with `T` being the type of the field.

If you want to have a Scala tuple as the key to the `ProcessWindowFunction` you need to define a `KeySelector`. The following snippet does the trick:

```
input
  .keyBy(a => (a._1, a._2))
  .timeWindow(Time.days(1))
  .process(new ProcessWindowFunction[(Int, Boolean, Int), Int, (Int, Boolean), TimeWindow] {
    override def process(key: (Int, Boolean), context: Context, elements: Iterable[(Int, Boolean, Int)], out: Collector[Int]): Unit = {
      out.collect(key._1)
    }
  })
```